# How to make a directory apache readable on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, webserver

Following problem:

I have an ubuntu 12.04 server I made a virtual host with

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
```

Everything is fine, I see the correct index.html when I point with webrowser to the website of this virtual host.
When I look to the owner of the **www** folder I see:

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jul 10 09:07 www
```

Now I change the DocumentRoot to

```
DocumentRoot /root/testFolder/
```

I copy my index.html in this folder, point with webrowser to my domain, then I get the message "*You don't have the permission...*"

Ok, I check the owner of testFolder

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Jul 11 08:18 testFolder
```

It is the same as www folder.

Ok my next try to change the group owner of testFolder

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /root/testFolder/
```

But I get the same result in my browser: "*You don't have permission to access / on this server.*"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

```
chown -R apache:apache /root/testFolder/
```

and

```
chmod +r /root/testFolder
```

**UPDATE**
The solution in this specific case was to move apache from under /root into a folder that doesn't require root privileges.

Comment: Thanks you. But I get the following message:
**chown: invalid user: `apache:apache'**

Comment: Can you try to move the folder to `/tmp/testFolder` and see if it works there ?

Comment: by accepting your answer I accept your comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think that the OS is preventing you from sharing folders/files under `/root`. It's an interesting question if it can be worked-around. I learned something too - thanks!

Comment: What the "standard Apache user"? `www-data`?

Comment: To find out the standard apache user: `ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1` (mind the 2 spaces after "-d\")